# How to Reset a Boundary Timer Time Cicle and/or Time Duration in Activiti 5.22.0?

Tags: alfresco, activiti, alfresco-enterprise

Does anyone know how can I programmatically reset a Boundary

Timer Time Cicle and/or Time Duration from a Java TaskListener using Activiti 5.22.0?

Comment: This question can be improved by adding concrete examples of what you have tried or providing more context.

Answer (score 0):

```
Can you please try this?

processInstanceId => process Instance ID 
jobs = processEngine.getManagementService().createTimerJobQuery().processInstanceId(processInstanceId).list();
TimerJobEntity tJobEntity = (TimerJobEntity) job;
tJobEntity.setDuedate(date);

where date is new date that we want to set.
```